# How would I turn this into a prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, statements

I'm new to prepared statements so I apologise in advance if this is a basic question but how would I turn the following code into a prepared statement and execute it later on?

```
<?php

$myQuery = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE ID=" . $_GET['ID'];

//run query
$result = $con->query($myQuery);
if (!$result) die('Query error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
?>
```

Comment: You start with the manuals http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php --- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements we're not here to do the work for you.

Comment: why did this question receive an upvote? *giving my head a shake here*. There is ZERO EFFORT done here.

Comment: Shake your head all you like! I've never come across a prepared statement. I've seen similar questions on here and watched a few youtube tutorials but they all seem to be done in a different context to what I'm trying to do and as I'm quite new to php it'd just help to see how this one in particular would look as a prepared statement. It's not always easy to find direct answers to stuff like this & you could have just ignored it

Comment: Ever heard of Google? Stack isn't a tutorial site.

Comment: Instead of talking down to me maybe you could help me out:
Would I include the prepared statement in every html page or would I save it as a separate document and "Include" it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php (mysqli lib), or http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php (PDO lib).

Ex:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Prepare statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE ID=?");

// set parameters 
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['ID']);

// execute
$stmt->execute();

// close resources
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just to clarify; would I include this on every html page that I wanted to us it or would I save it as a separate document and "Include" it?

Answer (score 0):

To do the call you could use somethign like;

```
$sCompanyCode = 'fkjahj12321';
$con = new PDO("connection string");

$sql = "SELECT CompanyID From Companies WHERE CompanyCode = :CompanyCode";
$st = $con->query( $sql );
$st->bindValue(":CompanyCode", $sCompanyCode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->execute();
```

To retrieve 1st or singular result;

```
if($row = $st->fetch()){ 
    return (int)$row[0]; 
}
```

For multiple results;

```
$aResults = array();
while ($row = $st->fetch()){
    $aResults[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just to clarify; would I include this on every html page that I wanted to us it or would I save it as a separate document and "Include" it?

Comment: it depends what pattern you are programming to. Take a look at OOP. You could for instance store this in a class. Or, leave on the page. If you want it on every page either a class or including a seperate file is a good idea.